# F# basics: turning NameValueCollection into nice string

Tags: .net, collections, f#

Learning F# while trying to do something useful at the same time, so this is kind of basic question:

I have `req`, which is a `HttpListenerRequest`, which has `QueryString` property, with type `System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection`. So, for sake of clarity let's say, I have

`let queryString = req.QueryString`

Now I want to produce nice string (not printf to console) from contents of that, but `queryString.ToString()` is not overriden apparently, so it just gives string "System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection".

So, what's the F# one-liner to get a nice string out of that, like "key1=value1\nkey2=value2\n..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
nvc.AllKeys
|> Seq.map (fun key -> sprintf "%s=%s" key nvc.[key])
|> String.concat "\n"
```

Comment: Accepted this over the other correct answer for looking nicer and being less imperative style.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this ought to work:

```
let nvcToString (nvc:System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection) =
    System.String.Join("\n", 
                       seq { for key in nvc -> sprintf "%s=%s" key nvc.[key] })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's good to have different versions to get perspective on the language, +1

Answer (score 1):

I use this code, which handles the case of keys that have multiple values, which is legal in a `NameValueCollection`, and I'm not seeing in the other answers. I'm also using the MS [AntiXSS library](http://nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS) to URL-encode the values.

*Edit:* Oops, I didn't read the OP closely enough. I assumed you wanted to turn `Request.QueryString` back into an actual query string. I'm going to leave this answer because it's still true that `NameValueCollection` allows more than one value per key.

```
type NameValueCollection with
    /// Converts the collection to a URL-formatted query string.
    member this.ToUrlString() =
        // a key can have multiple values, so flatten this out, repeating the key if necessary
        let getValues (key:string) =
            let kEnc = Encoder.UrlEncode(key) + "="
            this.GetValues(key)
            |> Seq.map (fun v -> kEnc + Encoder.UrlEncode(v))

        let pairs = this.AllKeys |> Seq.collect getValues

        String.Join("&", pairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

`kvs.AllKeys |> Seq.map (fun i -> i+ " = " + kvs.[i]) |> Seq.fold (fun s t -> s + "\n" + t) ""`

Extra inefficient and creating lots of string instances, directly from my head. :)

Comment: I'm not downvoter but you can't use `Seq.*` here since `NameValueCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<'T>`.

Comment: @pad What about using `Seq.cast` and `(|KeyValuePair|)`?

Comment: @pad Nope. The casted value in `kvs` is `seq<string>`.

Comment: [It was me.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a43kowi2ncI) -1 because this doesn't even compile and is, as admitted, inefficient.