# F# NameValueCollection to Map

Tags: json, dictionary, f#, mailmessage, namevaluecollection

I have a NameValueCollection which I need to convert to a Map and I just can't work it out.  I tried:

```
let headerMap (m : MailMessage) = m.Headers |> Map.map (fun k v -> v.[k])
```

Do I need to use Seq.map instead?

Basically the point of this is that I want to serialize the headers in a System.Net.MailMessage to JSON.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124865/f-basics-turning-namevaluecollection-into-nice-string

Comment: I asked the question on a Saturday afternoon and accepted on Saturday night, is that too slow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Daniel's answer will work just fine, but I thought I'd offer some additional alternatives:

**Array.fold** -- This should be faster than Daniel's version since it avoids the overhead of the iterators.

```
let mapOfNameValueCollection (collection : NameValueCollection) =
    (Map.empty, collection.AllKeys)
    ||> Array.fold (fun map key ->
        let value = collection.[key]
        Map.add key value map)
```

**Array.fold with sets of values** -- Similar to the code above, but returns the value as a `Set<string>` which may be useful if you want to determine if some value is in the returned set of values.

```
let mapOfNameValueCollection (collection : NameValueCollection) =
    (Map.empty, collection.AllKeys)
    ||> Array.fold (fun map key ->
        let valueSet =
            match collection.[key] with
            | null ->
                Set.empty
            | values ->
                Set.ofArray <| values.Split [| ',' |]
        Map.add key valueSet map)
```

**Recursive loop** -- Creates the map item-by-item with a recursive loop. I wouldn't use this in practice because the `Array.fold` version would be easier and faster. However, this approach could be faster if the specific collection class you're using (derived from `NameValueCollection`) overrides the `AllKeys` property and has some weird internal behavior which takes a long time to return the property value.

```
let mapOfNameValueCollection (collection : NameValueCollection) =
    let rec createMap map idx =
        if idx < 0 then map
        else
            let itemName = collection.GetKey idx
            let itemValue = collection.[itemName]
            let map = Map.add itemName itemValue map
            createMap map (idx - 1)

    createMap Map.empty (collection.Count - 1)
```

**Imperative loop** -- Creates the map item-by-item with an imperative loop. As with the recursive loop, I'd prefer to use `Array.fold` in practice unless there was some special reason not to.

```
let mapOfNameValueCollection (collection : NameValueCollection) =
    let mutable map = Map.empty

    let maxIndex = collection.Count - 1
    for i = 0 to maxIndex do
        let itemName = collection.GetKey i
        let itemValue = collection.[itemName]
        map <- Map.add itemName itemValue map

    map
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a NameValueCollection allows [more than one value per key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx). I don't know if a MailMessage ever uses it that way, but if it does none of this code will cover that case.

Comment: @JoelMuller All of these cases handle multiple values. The indexed `Item` property of `NameValueCollection` returns the same values as the `GetValues()` method, it just returns multiple values as a comma-separated string (CSV). My second case splits the CSV string and creates a `Set<string>` from the values, while the other cases return the CSV string directly (so the return type is Map<string, string>). The `Item` property probably uses `GetValues()` internally though, so it might be more efficient to use that directly instead of `Item`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the call to `Split`. My personal preference would be to avoid the extra work for the garbage collector created by the "array -> join -> string -> split -> array" sequence and simply call GetValues directly.

Answer (score 6):

```
nvc.AllKeys
|> Seq.map (fun key -> key, nvc.[key])
|> Map.ofSeq
```